# parsing json object to android

Tags: arrays, object

I am trying to load this list of objects from json into android.
It's json file

```
{"cofee":[{"ID":"1","name":"top1"},{"ID":"2","name":"top2"}]}
```

I use this fragment to load the json array.

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class east extends Fragment {
    ListView list;
    TextView id;
    TextView name;
    Button Btngetdata;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://url.com/east.php";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_ARRAY = "coffee";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    JSONArray coffee = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.east_fragment, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Btngetdata = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();  
            }
        });

    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        private JSONObject json;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            name = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
            id = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.id);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Getting JSON from URL
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                 // Getting JSON Array from URL
                 coffee = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);

                 for(int i = 0; i < coffee.length(); i++){

                     JSONObject c = coffee.getJSONObject(i);

                     // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                     String ID = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                     String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                     // Adding value HashMap key => value
                     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     map.put(TAG_ID, ID);
                     map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                     oslist.add(map);

                     list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                         R.layout.list_item,
                         new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME }, new int[] {
                             R.id.id, R.id.name});
                     list.setAdapter(adapter);
                     list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                     });
                 }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the app, there is nothing in my list. Here is it's LogCat:

```
 03-01 22:23:04.799: W/System.err(3348): org.json.JSONException: No value for coffee
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at com.mmmmmm.slidingmenu.slidinglist.east$JSONParse.onPostExecute(east.java:109)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at com.mmmmmm.slidingmenu.slidinglist.east$JSONParse.onPostExecute(east.java:1)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
 03-01 22:23:04.809: W/System.err(3348):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

App easily connects to server but I am newbie and couldn't recognize why it's unable to load the json arry??!!

Comment: Could it be that in the JSON it's spelled `cofee` but in the code it's spelled `coffee`?

Comment: looks like your jason has `cofee`, not `coffee`.

Comment: stupid me. that was it miss spelling in json array. thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" No value for coffee "

- Please check your json.
- You check your Json  at [JSON Formatter & Validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)
- If it is exactly the type of JSON, you check the code or you use  [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)